# Как найти все промежуточные точки в графе?

Tags: php

Необходима помощь знатоков. Есть граф в виде матрицы смежности представленной в массиве:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 8
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 12
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 9
        [6] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 8
        [5] => 4
        [6] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 12
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 3
        [5] => 6
        [6] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 8
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 7
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 6
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 7
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
    )
```

А так же есть алгоритм Дейкстры в виде кода:

```
    $maxDist = 9999999;

// Присваивание всем точкам бесконечный вес и информации о посещении.
foreach ($data as $key=>$i){
    $distance[$key] = $maxDist;
    $visited[$key] = false;
}

// Обозначение начальной точки 
$distance[$start] = 0;

for ($count = 0; $count < count($matrix); $count++) {
    $min = $maxDist;
    // Поиск точки с минимальным весом
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matrix); $i++){
        if (!$visited[$i] && $distance[$i] <= $min) {
            $min = $distance[$i];
            $index = $i;
        }
    }

    $u = $index;
    $visited[$u] = true; // Обозначение посещенной точки

    // Поиск наименьшего пути к точке.
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matrix); $i++){
        if(!$visited[$i] && $matrix[$u][$i] != 0 && $distance[$u] + $matrix[$u][$i] < $distance[$i]) {
            $distance[$i] = $distance[$u] + $matrix[$u][$i];
        } 
    }       
}
```

Данный код ищет кротчайшие пути ко всем точкам из начальной точки, однако необходимо задать и конечную точку и вывести список всех промежуточных точек, от начальной точки до конечной. Вопрос состоит в том, как найти список промежуточных точек? 
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот в тот момент, когда определяется кратчайший путь, нужно заодно записать в дополнительное поле для  `$i`-го узла, откуда в него было выгоднее прийти - из `$u` - а в конце размотать путь назад.

```
if(!$visited[$i] && $matrix[$u][$i] != 0 && $distance[$u] + $matrix[$u][$i] < $distance[$i]) {
        $distance[$i] = $distance[$u] + $matrix[$u][$i];
        $best[$i] = $u;
    }
```